# Grails- Criteria builders - createCriteria

Tags: groovy, grails, grails-orm, criteria

The Scenario is like this:
Every `Process` has multiple `ProcessingSteps`

The code that I have written is able to fetch all the processes without correspondence to `ProcessingSteps`.

I know that I am missing a where clause, I want to ask how do we do that in Grails.

I only want to fetch for each `Process` the corresponding `ProcessingStepUpdate`

I have two domain classes `ProcessingStep` and `ProcessingStepUpdate`

```
package a.b.c
public class ProcessingStep {
    Process process
}

public class ProcessingStepUpdate{
static belongsTo = [processingStep: ProcessingStep]
ProcessingStep processingStep
}
```

Here is the script that I was writing

```
Process.list(max:1).each {
    //List<ProcessingStep> test2= ProcessingStep.findAllByProcess(it)
    //println it
    def test3 = ProcessingStep.createCriteria().list() {
        eq("process",it)
    }
    println it

    it.list().each {
        //not telling it where to get the list from 
        ProcessingStep.list().each { pstep ->
            def test4 = ProcessingStepUpdate.createCriteria().list() {
                eq("processingStep",pstep)

                // Projections are aggregating, reporting, and
                // filtering functions that can be applied after
                // the query has finished.
                // A common use for projections is to summarize data
                // in a query
                /* projections{
                    groupProperty("processingStep")
                }*/
            }
            println pstep
            //List<ProcessingStepUpdate> test = ProcessingStepUpdate.findAllByProcessingStep(it)
            //List<ProcessingStepUpdate> test = ProcessingStepUpdate.findWhere()
            //println "it"
        }
    }
}
```

I have been stuck on this problem in one day.. new to OOPS world!

Comment: `Process` `hasMany` `ProcessingStep`s, `ProcessingStep` `hasMany` `ProcessingStepUpdate`s, correct? How do you want to choose, which  `ProcessingStepUpdate` to select for each `Process`?

Comment: BTW please use `hasMany`/`belongsTo`.

Comment: True. I will explain again.

Every process hasMany ProcessingSteps , and every `processingStep` `hasMany``ProcessingStepUpdate`. 

I want to chose Which `Process` has which `processingSteps`

Comment: Most of the task is still unclear for me. What does it mean "to choose", print all `ProcessingSteps` for a `Process`? Then how is it connected to `ProcessingStepsUpdate`s?

Comment: The `class processingStepUpdate` only give us the `end-time stamp` for each `processingstep` . That is the reason it is called the `ProcessingStepUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guesss that the task is only to iterate children of children. Then it is like this:

```
public class Process {
  static hasMany = [processingSteps: ProcessingStep]
}

public class ProcessingStep {
  static belongsTo = [process: Process]
  static hasMany = [updates: ProcessingStepUpdate]
}

public class ProcessingStepUpdate {
  static belongsTo = [processingStep: ProcessingStep]
}


Process.list().each{ process -> 
  process.processingSteps.each { step ->
    step.updates.each {
      println "Process: $process, Update: $it"
    }
  }
}
```

Or even

```
def updates = Process.list()*.processingSteps.flatten()*.updates.flatten()
println updates.join('\n')
```

Take a look a [Groovy Collections](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.21/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html), especially at "star-dot '*.' operator" section.

Comment: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: processingStep for class:Process`

That's the error I get now.

Comment: Of which code? There is no reference to "processingStep" in my loop sample, only to "processingSteps" (note "s").

Comment: The `class Process` is not present at-all.

The `Class ProcessingStep` has Object `Process` from which I have to refer from.

The `Class ProcessingStepUpdate` has Object `ProcessingStep`

Comment: 1. That opposes (again) to what you wrote in the question text (`Object`, not `Process`). You should really have included those details (in form of exact code quotation) at the very beginning. 2. You didn't answer all the questions I asked you, so I'm unable to help, sorry.

Comment: I found my error:

Here is the solution to the problem.


`//List of processes
Process.list(max:1).each {
def p=it
println it
// ProcessingStep.list(max:5).each {
     def test4 = ProcessingStep.createCriteria().list(){
      eq("process",p)
   }
   println test4`

Comment: it's not a solution, it's a misuse of the framework